# How to dynamically hide a column in jasper report using java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am well aware that `printwhenexpression` is used to hide or show a `column`. But how can I use it from Jave?  There is very little documentation of `JDesignExpression` available. How can I set a value to `false` for a `JDesignFrame`?

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

I don't know much how do I set any expression to a `StaticText` or `textfield` or `designframe`.

```
JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();

        expression.setValueClassName(Object.class.getName());
        expression.setValueClassName(measure.getValueClassName());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
textField.setPrintWhenExpression(new JRDesignExpression("$V{REPORT_COUNT} < 10"));
```

Use your specific condition expression instead of $V{REPORT_COUNT} < 10

Same settings work for JRDesignFrame too.

Answer (score 0):

add a condition that may help 
e.g

```
JRDesignExpression cond1 =
    OroJasperDesign
        .tool
        .createExpression("$P{docType}
        .equalsIgnoreCase(\"MER\") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE",Boolean.class);

band.addElement(OroJasperDesign
                    .tool
                    .createTextField(5, 70, pageWidth - 10, 30,
                                     textAlignment, null,
                                     orosoft
                                         .reports
                                         .jasperreports
                                         .OroReportFont
                                         .setFont(12, true, false, true),
                                     OroJasperDesign
                                         .tool
                                         .createExpression("$P{mepRmkInv}",
                                     String.class),cond1));
```